# Deserialize a String into a Field Type Java

Tags: java, deserialization

I'm currently working with the jedis Database library and a HashMap.

I'm in need for a method to deserialize a class from a HashMap. The target class wont use any datatypes except String and the primitive datatypes.

This is what I got currently:

```
public static <T> void Deserialize(T obj,final Map<String,String> map) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    Class objClass = obj.getClass();
    Field[] fields = objClass.getDeclaredFields();

    for(int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        fields[i].setAccessible(true);

        if(fields[i].getType() == String.class) {
            fields[i].set(obj, map.get(fields[i].getName()));
        }
    }
}
```

But is there another option instead of using a huge if else?

Comment: This design smells, and I'm not talking about roses. How did you end up having to deserialize classes from a map?

Comment: Interesting question, because this is the exact same thing I did when I ran into a fairly similar problem (the data came back from Javascript, which as we know is typeless). I couldn't think of a better way than an if-else structure based on the class, and if the classes didn't match or needed special handling then I specified the mapping for that specific attribute. I couldn't think of a better alternative with the given conditions.

Comment: If you have chance to change the HashMap thing then use JSON .. it will be much more easier

Comment: Redis is a simple Key,Value system. If I go a different way like Jsons It would destroy the design and it would be slower. For redis I could get the data as byte array aswell,but that wouldnt help. I though there would be something like the boost lexical_cast which can decide on runtime which way to go.

Comment: As Field.set requires two arguments both are `Object`s, I think above `for` does not require `if` statement... did you do the above without all the `if`s?

Comment: You could have each class you want to deserialize have a constructor that takes the map and retrieves the relevant data from it.

Comment: @vandale that would be like 20 lines of useless code for each class imagine i have +30 classes.

Comment: @bjlee72 Thats not possible as the value object of the map still would be a string a conversation is required here.

Comment: @Pete Changing `Map<String,String>` into `Map<String,Object>` does not solve the problem?

Comment: @bjlee72 As I said the String,String generic parameters are the given format the database doesnt allow it in a different way.